# Confused by JavaFX inheritance

Tags: java, javafx

a mock-up of an issue I'm having:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class tester extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    String ipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor"
            + "\nInteger nec odio."
            + "\nSed nisi. Nulla "
            + "\nPraesent mauris "
    + "\nPraesent mauris"
    + "\nPraesent mauris"
    + "\nPraesent mauris.";

    VBox root = new VBox(25);
    Label lblHeader = new Label("Place Holder");
    TextArea txtOutputBox = new TextArea(ipsum);
    Button btnSubmit = new Button("Submit");

    VBox.setMargin(txtOutputBox, new Insets(30));
    VBox.setMargin(lblHeader, new Insets(10,0,0,10));

    txtOutputBox.setFocusTraversable(false);
    txtOutputBox.setEditable(false);
    txtOutputBox.setFocused(false); // <---- The method setFocused(boolean) from the type Node is not visible

    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.getChildren().addAll(lblHeader, txtOutputBox, btnSubmit);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 250);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Unexplained");
    stage.show();
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    launch(args);

 }
}
```

Basically, I am using a TextArea control to display some text which is intended to be read only. For aesthetic purposes and so as not to miguide the user, I want to prevent the control from receiving focus.  I can easily set to false the FocusTraversable property but it's still possible to give the control focus by clicking within it (albeit, no editing can be done).

Reading through the documentation, TextArea says that it inherits the setFocused() method from Node, its distant relative.  When I look at this method the docs say that it's Protected.  Bingo I thought - but, my understanding of Protected was that it became available to all of the classes subclasses.  Therefore, I don't understand why it's not available to the subclass TextArea.

So, I have two questions.  In order of priority, the first would be great for my own education and understanding.  I've wasted half a day of trying to figure it out :-(  The second question would also be helpful if anyone has a quick suggestion.

1. Could someone explain why I can't access the Protected method of Node from the subclass TextArea (perhaps, one is not a subclass - but it seems to be).
2. Any suggestions as to how I could achieve what I'm trying to do here ?

Thanks anyone and all,

Comment: `setFocused` is protected. Protected means it is accessible to classes in the same package and classes that extend `TextArea`.  `setFocused` is also final so it can not be overridden.
_" how I could achieve what I'm trying to do here"_ what do you want to achieve  in addition to `.setEditable(false);` ?  If the text area can not be focused it can not be scrolled as well.

Comment: Even if you could access `setFocused(...)` here, it wouldn't do what you want. It would merely make sure that the text area wasn't focused when you start the application. If the user clicked on it, the internal mouse handlers would call `setFocused()` at that point, and it would receive focus.

Comment: You could style your `TextArea` differently so it doesn't _look_ focused, even when it is.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to your first question is that protected methods can be accessed *from* subclassesof `Node`. However, you're not accessing it from a subclass of `Node`, you're trying to access it from your `tester` class, which is not a subclass of `Node`. (In other words, you're *calling it on* the `TextArea` but trying to *call it from* another class entirely.)